# How to stick a toggled DIV ontop of toggle NavBar

Tags: css, mdbootstrap

In the below codesnippit I have a NavBar that is fixed to the bottom, and expands up when I click the right arrow, and when I click the left button I need a div to expand up, ontop of the NavBar and stick to it no matter the content of that div, but no matter which property for position I have tried, even tried flex, I am not able to get it to work.

Anyone who can help here?

**My code:**

```js
jQuery('.ExpandCollapsDIV').click(function(e) {
  jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- MDB -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-secondary" id="MessageDIVNav" style="position: absolute; bottom: 100px; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
  <font class="text-white" style="font-size: 12px;">
    <li>Top List 1</li>
    <li>Top List 2</li>
    <li>Top List 3</li>
    <li>Top List 4</li>
    <li>Top List 5</li>
    <li>Top List 6</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </font>
</div>


<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-lg bg-primary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <div class="ExpandCollapsDIV" data-mdb-toggle="collapse" data-mdb-target="#MessageDIVNav" aria-controls="MessageDIVNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <font class="text-white"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up fa-2x"></i></font>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
          <div class="ExpandCollapsDIV" data-mdb-toggle="collapse" data-mdb-target="#navbarSupportedContentBottom" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContentBottom" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="SystemInfodiv1"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down text-white fa-2x"></i></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContentBottom">
      <font class="text-white" style="font-size: 12px;">
        <li>Bottom List 1</li>
        <li>BottomList 2</li>
        <li>BottomList 3</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </font>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried:

`position: relative;` *optionally*

`z-index: 9999;` *i believe a higher number is on top and the default is zero*

Comment: Yes and all the 4 other properties of position. The Z-Index is regarding a different element, I have forgotten to remove it, will update..